# Regex to match url path - Golang with Gorilla Mux

Tags: regex, go, gorilla

I'm setting up an api endpoint which after parsing the url I would get a path such as `/profile/<username>` e.g. `/profile/markzuck`

The username is optional though as this endpoint returns the the authenticated users profile if username is blank

Rule set:
I'm not the best at regex but I've created an expression that requires `/profile` after that if there is a following `/` e.g. `/profile/` then you need to have a `<username>` that matches `(\w){1,15}`. Also I want it to be allowed to match any number of combinations if there is another following `/` e.g. `/profile/<username>/<if preceding "/" then anything else>`

Although I'm not 100% sure my expression is correct this seems to work in JavaScript
`/^\/(profile)(\/(?=(\w){1,15}))?/`

Gorilla Mux though is different and it requires the route matching string to always start with a  slash and some other things I don't understand like it can only use non-capturing groups
( found this out by getting this error: panic: route /{_dummy:profile/([a-zA-Z_])?} contains capture groups in its regexp. Only non-capturing groups are accepted: e.g. (?:pattern) instead of (pattern) )

I tried using the same expression I used for JavaScript which didn't work here. I created a more forgiving expresion `handlerFunc("/{_dummy:profile\/[a-zA-Z_].*}")` which does work however this doesn't really follow the same rule set I'm using in my JavaScript expresion.

I was able to come up with my working expresion from this SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28950606/gorilla-mux-regex)
And Gorilla Mux's docs talks a little bit about how their regex works when explaining how to use the package in the intro section [here](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux)

My question is what is a similar or equivalent expression to the rule set I described that will work in Gorilla Mux `HandlerFunc()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing this with mux, then I believe what you need is not regex, but multiple paths.

For the first case, use a path "/profile". For the one containing a user name, use another path "/profile/{userName}". If you really want to use a regex, you can do "/profile/{username:}" to validate the user name. If you need to process anything that comes after username, either register separate paths (/profile/{username}/otherstuff), or register a pathPrefix "/profile/{username}/" and process the remaining part of the URL manually.

Comment: I have been doing some more research and this does seem like the correct way to go. I think I can get the desired result with two maybe three routes that use mux `PathPrefix("/profile")` and using regex in in the subroute to match valid usernames. Will accept your answer after some testing with correct results.

Comment: This works `profilePrefix := router.PathPrefix("/profile")`  `profilePrefix.Path(\`/{username:\w+}\`)` any way I can replace the `+` with `{1,15}` as a username can only be 15 characters long?